# How can I get a list of all the users in a Tigase Xmpp server?

Tags: tigase

How can I get a list of all the users in a Tigase Xmpp server?

What I'd like to do is to allow a user to be able to select users from a list queried from the database, and add them into their Roster contacts list.

Comment: This might be a dangerous stunt to return all users to select as roster because of scalability, you need to change the implementation of a databased query function called inside getRoster(...) which gets called right after login ..... i would suggest you to run Tigase in debug mode using Eclipse and start looking for this function first .....

Comment: Hi @FLow. Thank you for the help. It's been very helpful. I will be going your way. You could post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Would you please mind looking at this other question I had posted earlier, still on a similar topic, [How to print new incoming XMPP Chat messages into Labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380401/how-to-print-new-incoming-xmpp-chat-messages-into-labels). I'll be very grateful. Thank you again.